# Angular - [error] Error: Cannot find module '../data/prefixes'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My Angular-13 application has been working fine. But suddenly when I want to run **ng serve --o** this morning, I got this error:

```
[error] Error: Cannot find module '../data/prefixes'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\postcss-preset-env\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:15:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
```

I checked the typescripts and my codes, but could not trace the error.

Comment: The tag for the actual program (Angular CLI runing ng serve) which trows the error is not specified

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I stated it did show me anything to trace the error.
I deleted the node_modules folder manually.
Then Install npm by running npm install.
So, everything becomes okay.
Thanks